Can't find a friend's clan
I'm trying to join a friend's clan (friend in the game) but the clan won't show up. I've tried with tag name as well.
It's not that multiple show up, it's that nothing shows up at all (though it is also a pretty weird clan name, so it's possible no other clan has it). This has happened for all of the clans my in-game friends are in that I've tried to join. Other clans I can join easily.
I don't think it's that I don't have enough trophies, because it should still show up (I didn't click the Joinable clans only checkbox).
Possible related, advanced searching for a clan doesn't show any results at all.
